# QGIS time manager plugin - animated trajectory: how to keep focus on a moving object

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I have just animated 4 different tracks from boats on the Ionian and Adriatic Seas by using time manager plugin. Everything works fine now (since I swiched over to shapefiles from GeoJSON).

The area covered by the tracks spans about 700km and I would like to render a video where time and speed labels are visible. So I would like to define a certain scale and keep one boat centered within the display during the time manager loop. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Not sure, but this could be helpful: https://medium.com/@tjukanov/geogiffery-in-a-nutshell-introduction-to-qgis-time-manager-31bb79f2af19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not implemented yet. There is an open feature request https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/179